# How adjust the Header/Footer?

Tags: header-footer

With this preamble :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{flshort}
\usepackage{shortvrb,latexsym}
\usepackage[french]{mylayout}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
\usepackage{pb-diagram}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% Les ensembles math{\'e}matiques, utilisant l'extension amsfonts
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\def\N{{\mathbb{N}}}
\def\Z{{\mathbb{Z}}}
\def\Q{{\mathbb{Q}}}
\def\R{{\mathbb{R}}}
\def\C{{\mathbb{C}}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Th\'eor\`eme}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollaire}[section]
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{D\'efinition}[section]
\newtheorem{exs}{Exemples}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Exemple}[section]
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remarque}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\newtheorem{cas}{Cas}
\newcommand{\p}{{\mathfrak{p}}}
\newcommand{\m}{{\mathfrak{m}}}
\renewcommand{\P}{{\mathbb{P}}}
\newcommand{\Rr}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\n}{{\mathfrak{n}}}
\renewcommand{\A}{{\mathbb{A}}}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{frenchb}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

I don't know how I can adjust the length of line in Header/Footer can someone help me to solve this problem?

**Edit (flshort.sty)**

```
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      % Contents: Special Commands for the LShort2e Introduction
       % $Id: flshort.sty,v 1.7 2001/11/25 17:43:58 matthieu Exp $
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
       % By Tobias Oetiker
          % Modified by Matthieu Herrb to handle the french extension
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     %\errorcontextlines=10
       %save pageref an label
     \let\lsspageref=\pageref
       \ProvidesPackage{flshort}
         \RequirePackage{verbatim}
    \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
    \RequirePackage{calc}
         \RequirePackage{ifthen}
       %
     % Lets have some nice headings
      %
  \pagestyle{fancyplain}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
   \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{} #1}}
      \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]
         {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
   \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]
       {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
    \cfoot[]{}
     \addtolength{\headheight}{1.6pt}
       %
        %
       % Earlier paragraphs were separated by some space
       %
             %\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
   %\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex plus 0.7ex minus 0.6ex}

        \newcommand{\manual}{\emph{\LaTeX{} Manual}~\cite{manual}}
            \newcommand{\companion}{\emph{The \LaTeX{} Companion}~\cite{companion}}
              \newcommand{\desgraupes}{\emph{\LaTeX{}, Apprentissage, guide et                            r�f�
              rence}~\cite{desgraupes}}
           \newcommand{\guide}{\emph{Local Guide}~\cite{local}}
            \newcommand{\contrib}[3]{#1\quad\texttt{<#2>}{\small\\\quad\textit{#3}}\\
            [1ex]}
           %
     % Some commands for helping with INDEX creation
        %
        % \protect added because needed with french package. --mh
        %
         \newcommand{\bs}{\symbol{'134}}%Print backslash
          %\newcommand{\bs}{\ensuremath{\mathtt{\backslash}}}%Print backslash
         % Index entry for a command (\cih for hidden command index
         \newcommand{\cih}[1]{%
          \index{commandes!#1@\protect\texttt{\bs#1}}%
           \index{#1@\protect\texttt{\hspace*{-1.2ex}\bs #1}}}
              \newcommand{\ci}[1]{\cih{#1}\texttt{\bs#1}}
          %Package
            \newcommand{\pai}[1]{%
          \index{extensions!#1@\protect\textsf{#1}}%
              \index{#1@\protect\textsf{#1}}%
       \textsf{#1}}
         % Index entry for an environment
        \newcommand{\ei}[1]{%
          \index{environnements!\protect\texttt{#1}}%
          \index{#1@\protect\texttt{#1}}%
         \texttt{#1}}
          % Indexentry for a word (Word inserted into the text)
          \newcommand{\wi}[1]{\index{#1}#1}
        %
        % Typesetting Commands
            %
              \newenvironment{lscommand}%
         {\nopagebreak\par\small\addvspace{3.2ex plus 0.8ex minus 0.2ex}%
          \vskip -\parskip
        \noindent%
     \begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline\rule{0pt}{1em}\ignorespaces}%
    {\\\hline\end{tabular}\par\nopagebreak\addvspace{3.2ex plus 0.8ex
     minus 0.2ex}%
        \vskip -\parskip}
          %
        % Type setting Code Fragments
       %
          \newenvironment{code}{\begin{quote}}{\end{quote}}
         %
           % Intro Environment
        \newenvironment{intro}{\sffamily}{\vspace*{2ex minus 1.5ex}}

         %
            %
              % Symbol Entry for Math Symbol Tables
                  %
                  \newcommand{\X}[1]{$#1$&\texttt{\string#1}\hspace*{1ex}}
                % normal text ....
                 \newcommand{\SC}[1]{#1&\texttt{\string#1}\hspace*{1ex}}
                      % for accents in text mode
                  \newcommand{\A}[1]{#1&\texttt{\string#1}\hspace*{1ex}}
                      \newcommand{\B}[2]{#1#2&\texttt{\string#1{} #2}\hspace*{1ex}}

                 \newcommand{\W}[2]{$#1{#2}$&
         \texttt{\string#1}\texttt{\string{\string#2\string}}\hspace*{1ex}}
          \newcommand{\Y}[1]{$\big#1$ &\texttt{\string#1}}  %
         % Mathsymbol Table
           \newsavebox{\symbbox}
         \newenvironment{symbols}[1]%
           {\par\vspace*{2ex}
          \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
           \begin{lrbox}{\symbbox}\hspace*{4ex}
          \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}}%
             {\end{tabular}\end{lrbox}\makebox[\textwidth]

             {\usebox{\symbbox}}\par\medskip}
               %
          % Special Prep for AMS Symbols Printout
           % Should work if AMS is not available
         %

            % we have no PS versions of the rsfs fonts ... so this is a nogo for pdf
           \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined % We're not running pdftex
            \IfFileExists{mathrsfs.sty}
                 {\RequirePackage{mathrsfs}\let\MathRSFS\mathscr\let\mathscr\relax}{}
           \fi
      \IfFileExists{amssymb.sty}
       {\let\noAMS\relax \RequirePackage{amssymb}}
        {\def\noAMS{\endinput}\RequirePackage{latexsym}}
      \IfFileExists{eucal.sty}
    {\RequirePackage[mathscr]{eucal}}
     {\IfFileExists{euscript.sty}
     {\RequirePackage{euscript}}{}}
      %\IfFileExists{eufrak.sty}
        %  {\RequirePackage{eufrak}}{}
       \IfFileExists{amsbsy.sty}
        {\RequirePackage{amsbsy}}{}


       %
           % Print |--| to show a distance
               %
   \newcommand{\demowidth}[1]{\rule{0.3pt}{1.3ex}\rule{#1}   {0.3pt}\rule{0.3pt}{1.3ex}}
     %
           % un morceau pour hyperref
              \def\realpageref#1{%
       \@safe@activestrue%
        \expandafter\real@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@secondoffive{#1}%
    \@safe@activesfalse%
        }

         %
              % --- example ----
           % This is an environment to set LaTeX examples.
               % On the left side the source text and on the
           % right side the typeset text.
              %
         % \begin{example}
              % \Large This is Large
         % \end{example}
                   %
                   % This Part is stolen from the verbaim.sty by FMi
                   %
                 \newwrite\example@out
                \newbox\exa@box
         \newcounter{exacnt}
          \setcounter{exacnt}{1}
           \newlength{\savefboxrule}
         \newlength{\savefboxsep}
        \newlength{\outdent}
            \setlength{\outdent}{2cm}
        \addtolength{\headwidth}{\outdent}

      \newenvironment{example}%
       {\begingroup% Lets Keep the Changes Local
       \@bsphack
      \immediate\openout \example@out \jobname.exa
       \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\catcode`\^^M\active
      \def\verbatim@processline{%
        \immediate\write\example@out{\the\verbatim@line}}%
      \verbatim@start}%
     {\immediate\closeout\example@out\@esphack\endgroup%
                            %
                            % And here comes my part. :-
                            %
          \setbox\exa@box=\vbox{% This box is mainly for debugging
         \stepcounter{exacnt}%
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
        % Page \lsspageref{exa:\theexacnt}
        \expandafter\ifx\csname r@exa:\theexacnt\endcsname\relax\else
      \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined % We're not running pdftex
      \ifx\@pr@ORI\undefined % We're not using french package
         \def\exa@page{\HyPsd@pageref{exa:\theexacnt}}%
        else %
      \def\exa@page{\@pr@ORI{exa:\theexacnt}}% french pageref is not a number
     \fi %
      \else %
      \def\exa@page{\HyPsd@pageref{exa:\theexacnt}}%
       \fi
         \ifodd\exa@page\hspace*{0pt}\else\hspace*{-\outdent}\fi%
       \fi
    \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
       \raisebox{-\height}[0pt][\totalheight]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\outdent+0.46\textwidth-3mm}%
    \small\verbatiminput{\jobname.exa}
     \end{minipage}}%
 \hspace{5mm}%
 \setlength{\savefboxrule}{\fboxrule}%
 \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}%
 \setlength{\savefboxsep}{\fboxsep}%
 \setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm}%
 \raisebox{-\height}[0pt][\totalheight]{%
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\outdent+0.54\textwidth-2mm-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep-0.7ex}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\savefboxrule}%
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{\savefboxsep}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
      %\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.4ex minus 0.2ex}%
      \setlength{\parskip}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}%
      \begin{trivlist}\item\small\input{\jobname.exa}
      \end{trivlist}
    \end{minipage}
    }%
  }%
  }\label{exa:\theexacnt}%
  } % end vbox
      %\showthe\ht\exa@box
   \par\addvspace{2.0ex plus 0.8ex minus 1ex}\vskip -\parskip
  \noindent\box\exa@box
  \par\addvspace{3.2ex plus 0.8ex minus 1ex}\vskip -\parskip
  }
    \newenvironment{lined}[1]%
   {\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{#1}\hrule\medskip}
     {\vspace{-1ex}\hrule \end{minipage}\end{center}}
    % I want no headers on pages created by clearpage

    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}
 {\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

      % French.sty redefined tilde. Grrr
   \ifx\@tildeORI\undefined
   \else
   \let\tilde\@tildeORI
    \fi
```

Comment: Adjust which part?  The text that appears there?  the (thickness, colour, length, etc. of) line that appears there?  where the page number is placed?  Which elements do you hope to have in the header, and which in the footer?

Comment: @jon, I want to adjust the length of line in header/footer.

Comment: I'm still not sure it is clear what you want the final result to look like... where should the line start and where should it end?

Comment: What are the contents of `mylayout.sty`?

Comment: @cslstr, I want that the line ends when the text stop.

Comment: @HarishKumar, I will add this.

Comment: Well the problem is probably in `\usepackage[french]{mylayout}`...

Comment: Please keep in mind @Adam's remarks about making your code a minimum working example that demonstrates your problem.  See [How to write a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/47522) for tips on how to do this effectively.

Comment: `mylayout.sty` is not the source of the problem. I also don't know of any `flshort.sty`. Where did it come from?

Comment: @karlkoeller, I will add the contents of flshort.sty.

Comment: I think you are making the life complicated. Instead of using all those (mylayout and flshort) you may do the job yourself using geometry and fancyhdr packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `flshort.sty` contains a line

```
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\outdent}
```

which is the culprit of the long header line.

Simply add this line in your preamble

```
\addtolength{\headwidth}{-\outdent}
```

and you will have the expected behavior.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{flshort}

\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % just for the example

% Les ensembles math{\'e}matiques, utilisant l'extension amsfonts
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\addtolength{\headwidth}{-\outdent}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{frenchb}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: hats off for reading and saving all those files and locationg the problem ;)

Comment: @Med You're welcome. Happy to help.